# Python: Program unexpectedly terminates

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I used Sublime Text 2 and ran the program in the terminal. Here is the code:

```
print("Welcome to QuizWow!")

while True:
    question = input("Enter the number of questions you will ask (up to 10): ")
###Program terminates after input: 'question' is answered by the user.
    if question == '1':
        qonea = input("Enter the question here: ")
        qoneaa = input("Enter the answer here: ")
        print ("1: ", qonea)
        qoneaguess = input("Enter your guess here: ")
        if qoneaguess == qoneaa:
            print ("Correct")
        else:
            print ("Incorrect")
```

Comment: How do you know that's where it ends? And do you get a stack trace?

Comment: I ran this code with both python2 and python3. In python2 it went into an infinite loop which is understandable because `input` in python2 is  looking for a number so the first if statement evaluates to false. However in python3, this ran perfectly. So can you show example input/output to help further diagnose this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) tries to execute what the user entered as Python code. According to the docs:

> This function does not catch user errors.
>   If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised.
>   Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.

So it's probably raising an exception and that terminates the program.

I think you want to use [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead.

Comment: Unless he/she's using python 3

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely with Sublime Text, not with your code.  A sublime install includes a limited version of python -- it can't take user input.  input() or raw_input() will not cause the expected behavior.  Run the .py file in your terminal and you should get the expected result.